# Making a vector of graphs in Lemon Graph Library

Tags: c++, lemon-graph-library

I created a graph and added nodes and transitions to it in Lemon Graph Library

```
typedef ListDigraph Graph;
vector<Graph> Process;
for(temp = temp.child("role");temp;temp = temp.next_sibling("role"))
{
    Graph proc;
    for(xml_node temp1 = temp.child("states").child("state");temp1;temp1 = temp1.next_sibling())
    {
        string state = temp1.child_value();
        state = role + "_" + state;
        vertex = process.addNode();
        state_name[vertex] = state;
    }
    Process.push_back(proc);
}
```

If I don't push it in vector everything works fine, but when I try to push it in `Process` I get error. Error is 70-80 lines long, but the main point I found is:

```
/usr/local/include/lemon/list_graph.h:336:5: error:
lemon::ListDigraph::ListDigraph(const lemon::ListDigraph&) is private
```

After doing what @Magtheridon96 suggested getting the following error:

```
    In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.6/i686-linux-gnu/./bits/c++allocator.h:34:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/allocator.h:48,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.6/string:43,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/locale_classes.h:42,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/ios_base.h:43,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.6/ios:43,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.6/ostream:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.6/iostream:40,
                 from usingleda.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/4.6/ext/new_allocator.h: In member function ‘void __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<_Tp>::construct(__gnu_cxx::new_allocator<_Tp>::pointer, _Args&& ...) [with _Args = {std::unique_ptr<lemon::ListDigraph>&}, _Tp = std::unique_ptr<lemon::ListDigraph>, __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<_Tp>::pointer = std::unique_ptr<lemon::ListDigraph>*]’:
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/vector.tcc:97:6:   instantiated from ‘void std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::emplace_back(_Args&& ...) [with _Args = {std::unique_ptr<lemon::ListDigraph>&}, _Tp = std::unique_ptr<lemon::ListDigraph>, _Alloc = std::allocator<std::unique_ptr<lemon::ListDigraph> >]’
usingleda.cpp:134:43:   instantiated from here
/usr/include/c++/4.6/ext/new_allocator.h:114:4: error: use of deleted function ‘std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>::unique_ptr(const std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>&) [with _Tp = lemon::ListDigraph, _Dp = std::default_delete<lemon::ListDigraph>, std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp> = std::unique_ptr<lemon::ListDigraph>]’
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/unique_ptr.h:256:7: error: declared here
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.6/vector:70:0,
                 from /usr/local/include/lemon/core.h:22,
                 from /usr/local/include/lemon/list_graph.h:26,
                 from usingleda.cpp:3:
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/vector.tcc: In member function ‘void std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::_M_insert_aux(std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::iterator, _Args&& ...) [with _Args = {std::unique_ptr<lemon::ListDigraph>&}, _Tp = std::unique_ptr<lemon::ListDigraph>, _Alloc = std::allocator<std::unique_ptr<lemon::ListDigraph> >, std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::iterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::unique_ptr<lemon::ListDigraph>*, std::vector<std::unique_ptr<lemon::ListDigraph> > >, typename std::_Vector_base<_Tp, _Alloc>::_Tp_alloc_type::pointer = std::unique_ptr<lemon::ListDigraph>*]’:
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/vector.tcc:102:4:   instantiated from ‘void std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::emplace_back(_Args&& ...) [with _Args = {std::unique_ptr<lemon::ListDigraph>&}, _Tp = std::unique_ptr<lemon::ListDigraph>, _Alloc = std::allocator<std::unique_ptr<lemon::ListDigraph> >]’
usingleda.cpp:134:43:   instantiated from here
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/vector.tcc:319:4: error: use of deleted function ‘std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>::unique_ptr(const std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>&) [with _Tp = lemon::ListDigraph, _Dp = std::default_delete<lemon::ListDigraph>, std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp> = std::unique_ptr<lemon::ListDigraph>]’
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/unique_ptr.h:256:7: error: declared here
```

Comment: _"but when i try to push it in Process i get error"_ - What error?

Comment: error is 70-80 lines long...but the main point i found is : "/usr/local/include/lemon/list_graph.h:336:5: error: ‘lemon::ListDigraph::ListDigraph(const lemon::ListDigraph&)’ is private
"

Comment: Judging by the error excerpt the copy constructor is made private to prevent copying.

Comment: Also if i create a vector for map of the graph and insert it in the vector i get smthng similar error

Comment: nyway to get around it ?

Comment: You cannot create a vector of a class that is not copyable. You can try to use smart pointers (like `unique_ptr`) and use a vector of smart pointers of `Graph`.

Comment: @Gonmator: Guess what, `unique_ptr` is not copyable.

Comment: @Gonmator: Please don't just throw smart pointers at every problem. Also, you may create a vector of objects of a type that is not copyable (as long as it is moveable, and the move assignment operator is marked `nothrow`).

Comment: @CatPlusPlus: it's true, `unique_ptr` is not copyable, so it's requires be emplaced instead pushed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not permitted to make copies of this object (This is what the author wants). The author of the library made the copy constructor private to ensure that you can't do this.

The solution is to change `std::vector<Graph>` to `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Graph>>`

That way, you don't need to make copies of the object as the author intended.

You would then allocate and insert like this:

```
std::unique_ptr<Graph> graph(new Graph);
// ...
vec.emplace_back(graph);
```

Comment: You should certainly NOT push a unique_ptr of a stack allocated object by taking it's address.  You should use `new` to allocate it.

Comment: I'm giving him a general solution. Whether he chooses to allocate on the stack or the heap is his choice, and he should definitely be allocating on the heap.

Comment: I have updated the answer to take note of this so he can avoid the error. Thank you for pointing it out Dave

Comment: grt..thnks...solvd the prblm...can you plz jst tell me one more thing.. now i have this... vector<ListDigraph::NodeMap<string> > names; and another vector - vector<ListDigraph::Node> state .... now i want to find out names[i][state[i]] ... that is... to which name state[i] maps to using map names[i] ... how do i do this..

Comment: It's best to create a new question for that.

Comment: If i use unique_ptr as you mentioned, then i am unable to use the functions of the Graph class. I am getting errors : "error: ‘Translator::up’ has no member named ‘addNode’" where "up" is "std::unique_ptr<Graph>"

Comment: `up->addNode` instead of `up.addNode`

Comment: I have edited my question to include the error i am getting after your suggested modifications.

Comment: You have to understand that `std::unique_ptr` is non-copyable but moveable and it can be moved around with `std::move`. Until you know how to use it properly on your own, you can get this all to compile by using `std::shared_ptr` which is copyable. (You would then call `push_back` instead of `emplace_back`)